# Multiplication by dirac delta

Tags: calculus

Let us consider $x<1$. Then if we consider $a\delta(x-1)$ where $a$ is constant. Then is it value for $a\delta(x-1)=0$ for $x<1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loosely speaking you can think of $\delta(x-x_0)$ as being $0$ everywhere except in $x_0$. So yes, for $x< 1$ it is $0$.

To gain further insight into this I recommend you look up the **theory of distributions**, which is a more formal way to think of mathematical objects such as the dirac delta. It is not a function in itself but only an object which affects a function when you integrate their product.